# Issue while moving existed file

Tags: linux, files, cron, mv

I have a script, that does queries to clickhouse stats data that's further used for monitoring.
Every query output is stored to `/tmp/file.out.tmp` file, and at the end of script that file is renaming to `/tmp/file.out`.
That script is running every minute by cron job, and all's going well until 02-04 am (local time), when errors like these appears:

```
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/file.out.tmp': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move '/tmp/file.out.tmp' to '/tmp/file.out': No such file or directory
```

although this file is in `/tmp/` directory. What thing can cause such behavior?

Comment: The file is clearly not in `/tmp` when those errors are being reported. Do you have some scheduled task that cleans out `/tmp`?

Comment: Isn't there a timer within systemd which cleans up temporary files within /tmp. `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` & `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service`?